# Symlinks look like regular files on samba shares

Tags: samba, file-sharing, cifs, symlink, smb-conf

Symlinks on my samba share aren't behaving the way I want them to – specifically, the links look like *duplicate regular files* to the client machine. This used to work (i.e. symlinks on the server looked like symlinks on the client), but at some point it stopped. So I assume it's related to the samba version somehow, but I've never found a combination that works.

Is it even possible to have symlinks work "like symlinks" on samba clients? If so, how?

Here's my setup.

**Server:** Synology NAS serving up a share via samba

```
------server smb.conf-------
[global]
unix extensions=no
follow symlinks=yes
wide links=yes
allow insecure wide links=yes
```

**Client:** Ubuntu 16.04 machine, mounting the share with the following command

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o vers=3.0 -o user=<myuser> //server/sharename /mnt/mountpoint
```

With the share mounted, here's what I do next:

**On the server**

```
$ echo "HELLO WORLD" > file-created-on-server.txt
$ ln -s file-created-on-server.txt symlink-created-on-server.txt
$ ls -iog
75852 -rwxrwxrwx+ 1 12 Jul 19 20:16 file-created-on-server.txt
75859 lrwxrwxrwx+ 1 25 Jul 19 20:53 symlink-created-on-server.txt -> file-created-on-server.txt
```

So obviously that's a symlink.
However, if I then do...

**On the client**

```
$ ls -iog
total 8
75852 -rwxr-xr-x 1 12 Jul 19 21:16 file-created-on-server.txt
75852 -rwxr-xr-x 1 12 Jul 19 21:16 symlink-created-on-server.txt
```

I expected *symlink-created-on-server.txt* to **look like a symlink**. But it doesn't. It looks like a duplicate of the original file – they even have the same inode number on the client, but not the server.

What is going on here? Is there a way to make symlinks just look like symlinks? I've read things about security issues with samba and symlinks, and I imagine that might be the reason the behavior changed, but I've never found a clear explanation – and in this case I don't care about the security implications.

Comment: Can you try to add the `linux` mount option? Otherwise there is the option to use `mfsymlinks` as client mount option, which will not implement a posix symlink but will create a file in the filesystem which describes the link and looks like a symlink to linux hosts that mounted with `mfsymlinks`, on Windows you will see a useless file =0).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing the same behavior from a Windows 10 client

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
unix extensions=no
follow symlinks=yes
```

That means that

1. The server won't report links
2. The server will follow the symlink.

The second option alone is probably enough to treat the symlink like a regular link, in other words as two names that refer to the same file.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I changed the smb.conf the way you suggested, restarted samba on the server, and unmounted/remounted the share on the client, and I still get the same behavior as before (symlinks look like regular files).